# Cannot open shared object file which is known

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cygwin

I am trying to execute a program I made on Qt throughout cygwin. It works that way on my development computer. Here I want to try it on a "new" environment.

When I type in cygwin the command : `./pm.exe -qws` it returns `path/to/executable/pm.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libQtXml.dll.4.8.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What I don't understand is that this library exists and is well set : When I do `which libQtXml.dll.4.8.7` it returns the right path where this file is... (this path is set in the $PATH and in the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables.)

I don't see what could cause the fact that the executable don't take this library into account.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try using `cygcheck pm.exe` to check the DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This made me realize that the problem does not come from the path of the libraries, because the command `cygcheck.exe pm.exe` returns `cygcheck: could not find 'pm.exe'`.

It is weirder than I thought... 
I am in the good directory, the autocompletion of the command worked)

Comment: Given cygcheck documentation, it seems you might need to add `./` if your program is not in `PATH`. Like so: `cygcheck ./pm.exe`

Comment: Oh ok thank you! Indeed, It looks like some cygwin dependencies are missing. I will launch a complete build tonight and I will see if this works better tomorrow!

Comment: IT WORKS !! 
Thank you so much, I was stuck for a long time on this ! It was strange because the error indicated was not related with the missing dependancies. But it works so thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : The error was related to missing *.dll files.

In order to know which dll is missing, run the command `cygcheck ./your_exe.exe` (Thanks to Benjamin T for the solution).